# ODBC. Able to test connection but unable to create dsn

Tags: odbc, dsn

Im trying to clone an database using ODBC.  However I do not have the Windows login or password to create the DSN.  I am able to make a successful test connection through PHP AND ODBC.

Is there anyway to dump an database or perhaps make it to a CSV safely using PHP?  Or is there anyway around this without the windows auth?

Answer (score 0):

If you are successfully connecting with PHP, then you should be able to use PHP to perform any ODBC calls necessary for duplicating or cloning the database supported via SQL Commands.

Since PHP is able to perform file io, you can choose to store the data from the database in any format you prefer; including csv.